# Add Geometry Attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to create a hypsometric curve from polygon shapefile and a DEM, and for that I am creating this model. Now, when I reach the Add Geometry Attributes step, I can't see AREA under Geometry Properties. I have added some more screenshots for further reference under the comment section, as I don't know how to add more than one image in the question.

[image]

Comment: What geometry type is the feature class or shapefile that is the source of the layer you are using for your Input Features?

Comment: Can you add your field and calculate the geometry (!SHAPE!.area)? Is this a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJyQR.jpg

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqDWU.jpg

Comment: @PolyGeo, it's a polygon.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Yes, I can compute shape area, as it's in a projected system, I have attached some more screeshots for further reference.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the geodesic area is unsuitable you can get the area from the projected geometry, all you need to do is decide on the correct spatial reference to calculate in, in this example it's 28355 (MGA94 zone 55):

```
# EPSG code of suitable projected CRS. Don't use the spatialReference object, 
# arcpy.SpatialReference(), it wont work though I can find no good reason why. 
SRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(28355).exportToString()  

def CalcProjectedArea(inGeom):
    global SRef # use the previous defined spatial reference
    return inGeom.projectAs(SRef).area
```

[image]

Or as a one liner:

```
!SHAPE!.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(28355).exportToString()).area
```

But that might get tedious if you're calculating a lot of geometries.

As at 10.2.1 if you try to use a spatial reference object in field calculator you will get `ERROR 000539: Error running expression:, RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject error creating spatial reference`, [to resolve this](http://dmahr.com/2016/08/geometry-operations-with-field-calculator/) use `.exportToString()` to get the projection string that will work in field calculator.

Comment: is there a way to do this in the model builder? So that I can add this as a step in my model and run the model.

Comment: Never mind, it worked out, thanks a lot Michael.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem.